# Should I set a compound index or two single field indexes for my operation in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql

So, I have data in the following model in `MongoDB`:

1. The default `_id`
2. A distint `uniq_id` (there will be multiple documents for each `uniq_id`)
3. A suitable timestamp value, ts for the document

Now, somewhere in my code, I wish to extract the oldest 100 documents for a given `uniq_id`. So I run this query:

```
db.students.find({uniq_id:"xyz"}).limit(100).sort({ts:1})
```

My questions now are:

1. How does `limit()` work? Will it use the default `_id` to get the first 100 documents? In other words, if I have 1100 documents resulting from `find()`, I know `limit(100)` is able to extract documents 1-100. Does it do this by making use of the default `_id` index?
2. To sort it based on timestamp (again to emphasize that I want the oldest 100 documents), do I need to set a compound index on both `uniq_id` and timestamp or is it better to create two single indexes on `uniq_id` and timestamp separately?

I am of the assumption that two single field indexes will do the job. Can someone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. limit(n) would return the first n results returned by the database. In your example query, the result is sorted by `ts`. When this is put through the query optimizer, MongoDB will *first* sort according to the given sort key and *then* limit the results.
2. You should use a compound index. But remember, [order matters](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#compound-indexes). So, as for your example, the compound index should be created

   ```
   db.students.ensureIndex({uniq_id:1,ts:1})
   ```
3. Use [`.explain()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to find out what suits you best.

HTH.